# JQuery write opening and closing ul tags around a script

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have this code here:

```
$(".entry-content h2").each(function( index ) {
                        $(this).wrap('<li></li>');
                    });
```

and this wraps opening and closing li tags around each h2 tag...how would I add the opening ul tag at the start and the closing ul tag at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method, using `closest()` to find the parent container and then `wrapInner()` to wrap the container's contents in a `<ul>`:

```
$(".entry-content h2").each(function (index) {
    $(this).wrap('<li />');
}).closest('.entry-content').wrapInner('<ul />');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nF6ea/

---

### Edit:

And another method, using `parent()` and `wrapAll()`:

```
$(".entry-content h2").each(function (index) {
    $(this).wrap('<li></li>');
}).parent().wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nF6ea/2/

Answer (score 0):

You just have to append the `li` into the `ul`.

```
var ul_element = $("<ul></ul>"); //since I don't know your markup
$(".entry-content h2").each(function( index ) {
    ul_element.append($(this).wrap('<li></li>'));
}).appendTo("whatever");
```

Answer (score 0):

try running this BEFORE wrapping the li tags:

```
$(".entry-content h2").each(function(index){
    if (index == 0)
    {
    $(this).prepend('<ul>');
    }
    else if(index == $("e.entry-content h2").length - 1)
    {
    $(this).append('</ul>');
    }
})
```